# Passing a local variable into an event handler

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling

```
h.d.d.w = Ext.extend(w.g.a,
{
    initComponent: function () {
      exampleFunctionA('Monday');
       //other fields omitted
    }
    exampleFunctionA: function (dayOfWeek) {
        this['WeekdayHoursStore' +dayOfWeek] = new Ext.data.Store({
            proxy: a.b.c.getProxy('d/e.asmx/f'),
            reader: g.h.i.j(
            [
              //array of config objects removed
            ]),
            sortInfo: //omitted
        });

        this['WeekdayHoursStore' +dayOfWeek].load(
        {
            params:
          {
              //parameters removed
          }
        });
        this['WeekdayHoursStore' +dayOfWeek].on("load", this._renderHours, this);
        //irrelevant code removed
    },

    _renderHours: function (dayOfWeek) {
        var dayIndex;
        for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){
            if(this.weekdays[i] === dayOfWeek){
                dayIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        var record = this.WeekdayHoursStore.getAt(dayIndex);
        this['UseDefaultValue' +dayIndex] = record.get("UseDefault");
    }
    //further class members omitted
}
```

How can I pass dayOfWeek into _renderHours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an anonymous function and call `this._renderHours` from it:

```
this['WeekdayHoursStore' +dayOfWeek].on("load", function() {
    this._renderHours(dayOfWeek);
}, this);
```

Comment: +1 but you could forgo the reference storage if you use an immediate function as wrapper.

Comment: @Martin Jespersen: The third parameter passed to `on` defines the scope. So it should work. I don't know ExtJS, but I looked it up and hope it works the way I understood it.

Comment: seems reasonable, i'm not an ExtJS user myself. My initial comment was to your unedited example tho, and there i just prefer currying instead of adding references to a parent scope. It seems cleaner, and for some reason not a lot of javascripters seem to use it